# Chromium - Error while building Chome_public_apk in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, chromium, ninja

I am trying to build Chromium for Android on an Ubuntu 16.04(LTS) machine as an Android Studio project.

> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md#Installing-and-Running-Chromium-on-a-device/

and then to create the Gradle for android studio, I followed the below.

> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md

and when I hit the below command in terminal. I got generated code for chrome_pubilc_apk

> build/android/gradle/generate_gradle.py --output-directory out/Default
>   --target //chrome/android:chrome_public_apk --project-dir ~/Projects/chrome_prototype/chrome_public_apk
>
> When I compile the code I got below compilation errors:-

```
Task :chrome.android.chrome_public_apk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/home/signity/chromium/src/out/Default/gen/base/jni_java/generated_java/input_srcjars/org/chromium/base/BuildConfig.java:2: error: duplicate class: org.chromium.base.BuildConfig
public class BuildConfig {
^
/home/signity/chromium/src/out/Default/gen/chrome/android/chrome_java/generated_java/annotation_processor_outputs/org/chromium/base/natives/GEN_JNI.java:8: error: duplicate class: org.chromium.base.natives.GEN_JNI
public final class GEN_JNI {
^
/home/signity/chromium/src/out/Default/gen/chrome/android/chrome_public_apk/generated_java/input_srcjars/com/google/android/gms/cast/R.java:5: error: duplicate class: com.google.android.gms.cast.R
public final class R {
^
/home/signity/chromium/src/out/Default/gen/chrome/android/chrome_public_apk/generated_java/input_srcjars/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/R.java:5: error: duplicate class: com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.R
public final class R {
^
/home/signity/chromium/src/out/Default/gen/chrome/android/chrome_public_apk/generated_java/input_srcjars/org/chromium/base/BuildConfig.java:2: error: duplicate class: org.chromium.base.BuildConfig
public class BuildConfig {
^
```

Comment: Do you see the same error message when using ninja to build Chromium?

Comment: @Asesh, using ninja, it is working fine. but when I split the project for android studio and after importing in the android studio then I got this error.

Comment: @Asesh, do you have any idea to fix this error.

Comment: I don't use Android Studio, so I have no idea. I use ninja for building Chromium. So sorry :(

Comment: @Asesh I am new to ninja, if I want to start development on Chromium using ninja, then what technology should I learn first? I am basically an android developer.

Comment: Chromium is mostly written in C++ for most of the platforms. For Android, it's written in C++ and Java. For macOS/iOS: C++ and Objective-C

Comment: @Asesh, if we want some modification in Chromium then should we have to change in the c++ code ? or if not pls can you suggest me steps required for modification in Chromium code

Comment: It depends, you might have to modify C++/Java or Objective-C code based on your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206423/discussion-between-achin-and-asesh).

Comment: Hi @Asesh, I want to change the version, for this, I have modified VERSION under chrome/src/chrome directory. But i while building i am getting below error.pls can you help in this

Comment: gen/components/policy/policy_constants.cc:75:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'kPropertyNodes'
      kPropertyNodes + begin_index;
      ^
gen/components/policy/policy_constants.cc:76:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'kPropertyNodes'
  const internal::PropertyNode* end = kPropertyNodes + end_index;
                                      ^
gen/components/policy/policy_constants.cc:92:19: error: no matching function for call to 'size'
  CHECK_LT(index, base::size(kChromePolicyDetails));

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to modify major version. The Chromium policy won't allow you change the major version. Try changing minor version instead. This is the version format Chromium uses: `major.minor.build.patch`

Comment: @Asesh, in the VERSION.text file, the current version is MAJOR=81
MINOR=0
BUILD=4037
PATCH=0

and i want to change it to 1.0.0.0, is it possible to change it or can we modify the  Chromium policy.

Comment: You can't change it. You will have to modify the build process to change major version

Comment: @Asesh, but if i try to change it for ios from XCODE  in the VERSION.text file then it is working fine and the version is changing to 1.0.0.0. i don't know why it is working with ios. please can you tell me how can I modify build process? i mean what files i have modify to change the version.

Comment: HI @Asesh, pls do you have any idea how to print the log in c files and send the logs to android studio console in the Chromium?

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing similar issue on android studio.

But if you want to change the version, do this;
Modify AndroidManifest.xml (src/chrome/android/java/AndriodManifest.xml )

Add the VersionName or version code as you need
 android:versionName="AAA.BBB.CCC"